# how to convert from CVS to existing excel file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, import, copy

I am trying to convert a CSV file to an existing excel file named '*bench_configuration*'.
Inside this Excel there are few sheets. I want to convert the CSV file into a sheet named '*Setup_Loss*' (which is already inside the EXCEL file)

I tried to use :

```
read_file = pd.read_csv('new_names.csv',sep='\t')
read_file.to_excel('bench_configuration.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```

But its opening a new Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an instance of ExcelWriter and use it to write and save the content

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook as lw

workbook = lw('bench_configuration.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('bench_configuration.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') 
writer.book = workbook
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook.worksheets)

read_file = pd.read_csv('new_names.csv',sep='\t')
read_file.to_excel(writer, "Setup_Loss")

writer.save()
```

Comment: It is not working. It did not copy the CSV to the existing excel file

Comment: When, you are using the code snippet, what happens?

Comment: Just opening a new Excel file with all the details from the CVS file, instead of opening the existing excel file (which is in the Desktop ) and copy into the details from the CSV file

Comment: Do you want to append the content to the existing sheet or just dump the content in the existing sheet removing older content?

Comment: just dump the content in the existing sheet removing older content....just to modify

Comment: I have edited my code snippet in the answer. Please have a look. I think, it should work now

Comment: Works !
But the thing is that now in each row I have a string and I need to split a list in one column into 2 more columns And have the option to change the name of each column

Comment: I tried :
df = pd.read_csv('new_names.csv', skiprows=[0, 1], sep=' ') 
df.to_excel('bench_configuration.xlsx', index=None, header=True) Its is not split a list in one column into 2 more columns